# SCons support for visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, scons

Does anyone know when scons will support Visual Studio 2013?

The latest release, 2.3.1, is hard coded to look for 6.0 up to 11.0. But no entries for 12.0.

VS 2013 has been released for a few months. I'm surprised this is lacking.

Thanks
Shane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio is now part of the latest scons releases. If this will not work for you I suggest look at hplate's answer.

Answer (score 5):

I too was looking for VS 2013 (vs12) support (for  scone 2.3.0) and I found this link:

[D146 SCons visual studio 2013 support](https://developer.blender.org/D146)

I made the same simple changes to the 3 files as described there, and, voila, vs12 now works...

Answer (score 2):

---

Unmarking as an answer. Turns out there was an issue on a machine with just VS2013.

I managed to work around it by calling

```
SCons.Tool.MSCommon.vc.​__INSTALLED_VCS_RUN=['12.0']
```

It works. But such a bad practice that I can't encourage it in good faith.

---

It turns out official support is still pending. I've talked to the developers and they believe it should be part of the next release.

Like hplate I came across a patch for scons.

https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/pull-request/104/support-visual-studio-2013/diff

The code here only supports VS2013 Express. But it was simple to modify it for VS2013.

That worked well enough. But I did not want to force ~300 other developers to use a patched version of scons.

Luckily our build system creates one Environment & clones it as needed. My solution

```
def RegGetValue(root, key, _32bit = True):
    """This utility function returns a value in the registry
    without having to open the key first.  Only available on
    Windows platforms with a version of Python that can read the
    registry.
    """
    if not SCons.Util.can_read_reg:
        print "ERROR: Python cannot read the Windows registry! - Crashing out..."
        sys.exit(-1)

    p = key.rfind('\\') + 1
    keyp = key[:p-1]          # -1 to omit trailing slash
    val = key[p:]

    if _32bit:
        flags = 0x20219 # KEY_READ (0x20019), KEY_WOW64_32KEY (0x0200)
    else:
        flags = 0x20119 # KEY_READ (0x20019), KEY_WOW64_64KEY (0x0100)

    try:
        k = SCons.Util.RegOpenKeyEx(root, keyp, 0, flags)
    except Exception as e:
        import traceback
        traceback.print_stack()
        print "ERROR: Python cannot read the Windows registry (" + key + ")"
        print "Please ensure you have the correct Visual Studio, Micrsoft SDK, and ​.NET installed"
        print "Crashing out....."
        sys.exit(-1)
    return str(SCons.Util.RegQueryValueEx(k,val)[​0])

# As of version 2.3.1 scon's does not have built in support for Visual Studio 2013.
# Manually setting the appropriate environmental settings after the env has been created.
# Once scons officially supports 2013 consider removing these.  

# HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client\InstallPath
# C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
dot_net4_directory = RegGetValue(SCons.Util.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\NET Framework Setup\\NDP\\v4\\Client\\InstallPath", _32bit=False)
# HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Setup\VS
# C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\
vs_2013_directory = RegGetValue(SCons.Util.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\12.0\\Setup\\VS\\ProductDir")
# HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows Kits\Installed Roots\KitsRoot81
# C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\
kit8_1_directory = RegGetValue(SCons.Util.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows Kits\\Installed Roots\\KitsRoot81")
# HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\InstallationFolder
# C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\
# Need to investigate if this should be 8.1A
sdk_8_1_directory = RegGetValue(SCons.Util.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v8.1\\InstallationFolder")

LIBPATH = (
    dot_net4_directory + ';'
    + vs_2013_directory + 'VC\\LIB\\amd64;' 
    + vs_2013_directory + 'VC\\ATLMFC\\LIB\\amd64;' 
    + kit8_1_directory + 'References\\CommonConfiguration\\Neutral;' 
    + '\\Microsoft.VCLibs\\12.0\\References\\CommonConfiguration\\neutral'
)

LIB = (
    vs_2013_directory + 'VC\\LIB\\amd64;'
    + vs_2013_directory + 'VC\\ATLMFC\\LIB\\amd64;'
    + kit8_1_directory + 'lib\\winv6.3\\um\\x64'
)

PATH = (
    vs_2013_directory + 'Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TestWindow;'
    + vs_2013_directory + 'VC\\BIN\\amd64;'
    + dot_net4_directory + ';'
    + vs_2013_directory + 'VC\\VCPackages;'
    + vs_2013_directory + 'Common7\\IDE;'
    + vs_2013_directory + 'Common7\\Tools;'
    + vs_2013_directory + 'Team Tools\\Performance Tools\\x64;' 
    + vs_2013_directory + 'Team Tools\\Performance Tools;' 
    + kit8_1_directory + 'bin\\x64;' 
    + kit8_1_directory + 'bin\\x86;' 
    + sdk_8_1_directory + 'bin\\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\\x64\\;'
    + 'C:\\Windows\\System32'
)

INCLUDE = (
    vs_2013_directory + 'VC\\INCLUDE;'
    + vs_2013_directory + 'VC\\ATLMFC\\INCLUDE;'
    + kit8_1_directory + 'include\\shared;'
    + kit8_1_directory + 'include\\um;'
    + kit8_1_directory + 'include\\winrt'
)

# Setup the Visual Studio 2013 variables
# Note: The default 'ENV' values are fine
# on a machine with VS2008 & VS2010 installed
# Unclear about machines with just VS2013.
# Needs investigation.
# env['ENV']['TMP'] = default
# env['ENV']['COMSPEC'] = default
# env['ENV']['TEMP'] = default
# env['ENV']['SystemDrive'] = default
# env['ENV']['PATHEXT'] = default
env['ENV']['LIBPATH'] = LIBPATH
env['ENV']['LIB'] = LIB
env['ENV']['PATH'] = PATH
# env['ENV']['SystemRoot'] = default
env['ENV']['INCLUDE'] = INCLUDE

env['MSVC_VERSION'] = '12.0'
env['GET_MSVSPROJECTSUFFIX'] = '.vcxproj'
env['MSVSPROJECTSUFFIX'] = '.vcxproj'
env['MSVS'] = {'SOLUTIONSUFFIX': '.sln', 'PROJECTSUFFIX': '.vcxproj'}
env['MSVSENCODING'] = 'utf-8'
env['MSVS_VERSION'] = '12.0'
```

Caveat: So far I've only tested this on a machine with VS2008, VS2010, & 2013 installed. I'm going to test it on VS2013 only machine and will update this post if there are any issues.

Answer (score 1):

FYI. VS2013 support should be available in the next release of SCons (aka 2.3.2). The pull requests have been merged.

https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/pull-request/104/support-visual-studio-2013/diff

https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/pull-request/120/adding-support-for-visual-studio-2013/diff

Comment: As of July 5, 2014, scons 2.3.2 is available.